# Spotify Auth Flow React-Native-CLI IOS

Tags: react-native, spotify

I'm currently building an ios app using react-native and I want to be able to have the user sign in with their spotify account through my app. I don't really know what I'm doing and right now it seems like I'm just throwing up docs into my code to try to get it to work. I'm having difficulty finishing the auth flow and retrieving the token. I will share my code below for your reference. Right now when the user clicks on the sign in with spotify button it takes them to the webview to sign in. Once the user signs in with their account it then asks them to accept the terms. Once the user accepts the terms it should complete the auth flow and return the token. However in my application after the user accepts the terms it just closes the window and seems to get stuck because nothing is printed to the terminal when it should be. I will be sharing my info.plist, Auth.js, and SettingsScreen.js.

Info.plist

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.client</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.client</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Auth.js * some code is commented out because it wasn't being executed anyways... you can ignore those parts. When I run my project only the redirectURl is printed to the terminal and not the line after the authorize command.

**Redirect URL == com.client://callback**

```
import {authorize, refresh} from 'react-native-app-auth';
import {Spotify_ClientID,Spotify_ClientSecret,Spotify_RedirectURI} from '@env';
class AuthenticationHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.spotifyAuthConfig = {
      clientId: Spotify_ClientID,
      clientSecret: Spotify_ClientSecret,
      redirectUrl: Spotify_RedirectURI,
      scopes: [
        'playlist-read-private',
        'playlist-modify-public',
        'playlist-modify-private',
        'user-library-read',
        'user-library-modify',
        'user-top-read',
        'user-read-email'
      ],
      serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
        tokenEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      },
    };
  }

  async onLogin() {
    try {
      // contact spotify server
      console.log(this.spotifyAuthConfig.redirectUrl);
      const result = await authorize(this.spotifyAuthConfig);
      console.log('finished');
      // console.log('Access Token:', result.accessToken);
      // console.log('Refresh Token:', result.refreshToken);
      // console.log('idk');
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      // const { accessToken, accessTokenExpirationDate } = result;
      // const validationMessage = `User logged in successfully. Token: ${accessToken}, Expiration Date: ${accessTokenExpirationDate}`;
      // console.log(validationMessage);
      // alert(validationMessage);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log('Error:', error.message);
      console.log('Stack Trace:', error.stack);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    } 
  }

  async refreshLogin(refreshToken) {
    const result = await refresh(this.spotifyAuthConfig, {
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
    });
    return result;
  }

}

const authHandler = new AuthenticationHandler();

export default authHandler;
```

SettingsScreen.js

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import styles from "./Styles";
import backendURL from "../../constants/backend";
import authHandler from "../../utils/Spotify/Auth";

const SettingsScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleGoBack = async () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleGoBack}>
        <Text>Go Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>Settings</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> authHandler.onLogin()}>
        <Text>Sign in with Spotify</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SettingsScreen;
```

I know there must be a simple solution to this I just cannot find it. Please Help! Thanks!